# python Image.save changes the data

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

It seems that python has its own mind..

Here is how it looks in IDLE:

```
>>> a = Image.open("1.jpg")
>>> a.save("2.jpg")
>>> b = Image.open("1.jpg")
>>> c = Image.open("2.jpg")
>>> c == b
False
>>> c.getdata() == b.getdata()
False
>>> c.getdata()[0]
(243, 217, 130)
>>> b.getdata()[0]
(245, 215, 129)
>>>
```

## ?!

I have tried it with different images, all came back like that..

thanks for helping :)

Comment: There's probably a typo here: "1.jpg" and "a.jpg" are different images, so their `getdata` and pixel values aren't the same, as it should be.  (and you never do anything with Python object `a`, or "2.jpg")

Comment: they are all the same picture (originaly called "sckrnvjs1443" and saved as "sckrnvjs1443output"). I changed the names in order to be more clear, but by mistake I didn't change all the names accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with JPEG. JPEG is a [lossy format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) and will generally not produce exactly the same data when you save a file. Depending on quality settings, it might not even be very close. This behavior is by design. To avoid this, don't use a lossy format. In particular, do not repeatedly load a JPEG, modify it, and save it as JPEG again. This produces generation loss, where the image gets a little worse each time you save it.